# display.setText("@string/sport"); Why wont the string "sport" be displayed?

Tags: android, string

```
display.setText("@string/sport");
```

sport is a string function declared in Strings.xml however in the app it is not showing up?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
display.setText(R.string.sport);
```

`@resource/name` references only work in XML code. When using Java, the format is `R.<type>.<name>`.